# Splitting windows

Tags: neovim, split

Is there any way I can split the window as illustrated in the image?

[image: split window]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do:

1. Go to the first split
2. Create a horizontal split (`:split` or <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`s`)
3. Go to the newly created split (<kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`j`)
4. Make it span the full horizontal band (<kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`J`)
5. Go to the second split (<kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`k` <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`l` <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`l`)
6. Make it span the full vertical band (<kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`L`)

Comment: thanks a lot, made my day.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: Or to get vim help on the topic use the command:

`:h split`